# Time intervals chart

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

I'm a relatively new ios developer. I am developing an app for iphone and i need a free library to do a chart in which to display time intervals. The typical use of such a chart is to diplay different activities in a day. The chart is similar to a Gantt, with time on the x-axis and activities on the y-axis; the difference between the two types is that in the former there can be multiple intervals for the same activity. Unfortunately I cannot post an image due to the fact I am new to stackoverflow.

Can anyone point me to such a library? Tanks a a lot, Mattia.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of below two as per you requirement

1. MIMChartLibrary
2. Coreplot

As per your requirement, it is better to use MIMChartLibrary. You can easily integrate it to your application.

Comment: Well, none of the two libraries indicated can help me because they don't provide plot I described. Any other solution?